# Deck.gl, how to define different colors of scatter plot based on values from a column

Tags: javascript, deck.gl

this is literally my first JS code, so please bear with me, I manage to adapt a sample example from Deck.Gl to show a scatter plot, now I am not sure how to change colors based on the value of the column "Status", I know how to do it for 1 value but not sure how to do the rest using if then else here

```
getFillColor: d => (d[2] === '1-pile' ? [0, 128, 255] : [255, 100, 128])
```

here is a full reproducibe example

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>deck.gl solar Farm  Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@^7.0.0/dist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>      
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const {DeckGL, ScatterplotLayer} = deck;  
    new DeckGL({
      mapboxApiAccessToken: 'xxxxx',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9',
      longitude: 5.2,
      latitude:  35.49,
      zoom: 15,
      minZoom: 5,
      maxZoom: 20,
      pitch: 40.5,
      layers:[ 
        new ScatterplotLayer({
        id: 'scatter-plot',
        data: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djouallah/interactivie_map/master/data.json',
        radiusScale: 3,
        radiusMinPixels: 0.25,
        getPosition: d => [d[0], d[1], 0],
        getFillColor: d => (d[3] === '1-pile' ? [0, 128, 255] : [255, 100, 128])
      })
      ]
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution (and I too am not a javascript developer) could be to create a function which returns the colour based on the variable

```
function get_colour( d ) {
        if( d === '1-pile' ) {
            return [0,128,255]
        } else if ( d === '2-Tracker') {
            return [255,100,128]
        } else if ( d === '3-module') {
            return [128, 128, 128]
        } else {
            return [255, 255, 255]
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it for the `getFillColor` prop

```
getFillColor: d => get_colour( d[3] )
```